# How to pass out of scope variables to anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function, scoping

I am new in PHP.

I want to create a function link this.

```
public static function cat_post($category, $limit, $top)
{
    $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q)
        {
            $q->where('name', 'like', $name);
            $q->where('top', 'like', $top);

        })->take($limit)->get();
}
```

But i got

```
Undefined variable "name"
```

Please help me. How to create this function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as below:

```
public static function cat_post($category, $limit, $top)
{
    $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($name, $top)
        {
            $q->where('name', 'like', $name);
            $q->where('top', 'like', $top);

        })->take($limit)->get();
}
```

have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)